# UART interrupt handling using FreeRTOS

Tags: stm32, c, embedded, rtos, freertos

I have two threads:
1. ReadFromUART(): It reads from UART (RX), parses the message and put a command on the messageQueue
2. CommandHandler(): If a message is present in the messageQueue, It execute some instructions then it sends a message via UART (TX)

```
void CommandHandler(void const * argument)
{
    osEvent event;
    uint32_t x;
  for(;;)
  {
        event = osMessageGet(pkQueueHandle, 100);
        if (event.status == osEventMessage)
    {
            x = event.value.v;
            if (x == STOP)
            {
                if (HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart1, bufferTX_Stop, sizeof(bufferTX_Stop)) != HAL_OK)
                {
                    Error_Handler();
                }
            }
            if (x == PAUSE)
            {
                if (HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart1, bufferTX_Pause, sizeof(bufferTX_Pause)) != HAL_OK)
                {
                    Error_Handler();
                }               
            }
            if (x == RESUME)
            {
                if (HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart1, bufferTX_Resume, sizeof(bufferTX_Resume)) != HAL_OK)
                {
                    Error_Handler();
                }               
            }
            if (x == START)
            {
                if (HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart1, bufferTX_Start, sizeof(bufferTX_Start)) != HAL_OK)
                {
                    Error_Handler();
                }               
            }
        }
    osDelay(1);
  }
}

void vReadFromUART(void const * argument)
{
    uint32_t cmd_ID;
  for(;;)
  {

        if (HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1, (uint8_t *)bufferRX, 2) != HAL_OK)
    {
            Error_Handler();
    }

        if (memcmp(bufferRX, "ST", 2) == 0)
            cmd_ID = START;
        if (memcmp(bufferRX, "PA", 2) == 0)
            cmd_ID = PAUSE;
        if (memcmp(bufferRX, "RE", 2) == 0)
            cmd_ID = RESUME;
        if (memcmp(bufferRX, "SP", 2) == 0)
            cmd_ID = STOP;


        if (osMessagePut(pkQueueHandle, cmd_ID, 100) != osOK)
        {
            Error_Handler();
        }
    while (HAL_UART_GetState(&huart1) != HAL_UART_STATE_READY);
    osDelay(1);
  }
  /* USER CODE END vReadUARTCommand */
}
```

As you can see, I'm using UART interrupts (RXNE and TC) to handler UART data flow. The problem is interrputs are no longer detected. I thought this could be caused by context switching, I used `vTaskSuspendAll()` before `HAL_UART_Receive_IT()` but the problem is still there.

I want to understand how to handle UART interrupts with FreeRTOS

Comment: At the end of your `vReadFromUART()` do you intend for the `osDelay(1)` to be inside the `while()` loop or outside? As you have it written now that loop will probably never exit because it's stuck in that task...

Comment: consistent indenting of the posted code would make it massively easier to read/understand

Comment: The posted code does not handle certain conditions.  For instance, when the code processing gets out of step with the incoming data.  Is there any criteria that states the incoming data will be all upper case?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because software

Comment: @DavideAndrea, can you elaborate on that? "_the writing of firmware for bare-metal or RTOS applications_" is explicitly mentioned as [on-topic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site.

Comment: By the way, I'm not saying this is a good question. It lacks (debugging) details and that is a valid close reason. For example "_The problem is interrputs are no longer detected._" (how is this conclusion made?) "_I thought this could be caused by context switching_" (what would context switching have to do with this?). "_I want to understand how to handle UART interrupts with FreeRTOS_" (This is way too broad to be on-topic). The question could be improved by OP, but given that's it more than 5 years old, I guess it won't be...